# Local rate of convergence for fixed point iteration with unique statonary point implies global?

Tags: fixed-point-iteration, rate-of-convergence

Suppose one has a fixed point iteration $$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$ which is known to converge to a unique stationary point $x^*$, regardless of the initial value $x_0$. Suppose further that it is known that in some neighborhood of the solution, the rate of convergence is linear.

**Can we infer any global convergence properties from the above?** Any resources would be helpful.

Comment: You have already assumed global convergence regardless of the initial condition.  It might take a long time to get in the region where error begins to decay exponentially.  Consider for example the case $x \geq 0$ and a continuous and piecewise linear function $f(x)$ that starts at the origin and increases with slope $1/2$ over $x \in [0,1]$, then increases with slope $1$ over $x \in [1/2, \infty)$.   If we start at a very large $x_0>0$, the error decreases by constant steps until we get to the desirable region.

Comment: In this case the rate is linear globally. I guess you might be able to make a more complicated function, but it's hard for me to imagine.

Comment: How do you conclude that this example is "linear globally"?  And what is your definition of that?